# Restyle React child components dynamically from parent by a certain property

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a chess game I am building with React-Redux...

The issue I am having is how to highlight the squares available for a piece to move to with my current architecture.

I've tried passing data from the children to the parent via props, but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using refs and ran into a lot more goofy issues. I think I am missing something obvious here...

```
<Board/>
```

is made up of an array of 64:

```
<Square key={} />
```

components. Each has a key prop that is a chess square ID, like "a8" or "f6".

I have a method of my `App` component that returns an array of available squares to move to when one clicks a piece.

```
calculateAvailableSquares(pos, piece, board){
   //returns an array like ["f5", "f4","f3"]
   //TODO get this function to highlight the <Square/>s
   /// that have a key within the returned array
}
```

How can I fire a method in my `App` component and pass an updated `className` or `style` prop to all and only the `Square` components who's keys are in the array?

I don't understand how to select these children in React, and I don't understand how, once I would have them selected, I would alter them dynamically like this.

Comment: Show the code of the render method.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you are using Redux, so you could set your global state of which squares are highlighted by calling one of your Redux reducers.

Alternatively, a quicker and easier way to do it would be to pass a function from the parent component to all the child components.

```
class ParentComponent {
    state = {
        highlightedSquares: []
    }

    setSquareState = square => {
        const highlightedSquares = this.state.highlightedSquares.push(square)
        this.setState({ highlightedSquares })
    }


    render() {
        <div>
            <Square setSquareState={this.setSquareState} />
        </div>
    }
}


const Square = props => (
    <div className={props.isHighligted ? "highlighted" : ""}>
        <button onClick={props.setSquareState}>Highlight</button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Hey Stretch0. I just solved this issue by using the main Redux store to store the array. No idea why I didn't think of that sooner! Thanks anyway though!